# TKInter global variable for button

Tags: python, tkinter

I use a multiple frame window from *Steven M. Vascellaro* example [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter).
And I don't understand is it possible to use global variable, because each frame is  destroyed every time it is changed. 1st (of 2 buttons) button at `StartPage` is deactivated, if I click on 2nd button and go to `PageOne` and do something there and return to StartPage 1st button must be activated.

If I declare `global` in `StartPage` class

`_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!startpage.!button2"`

If I declare it in `PageOne` class

`NameError: name 'install_svc' is not defined`

Not good idea, but I think about 3rd frame where I define buttons again.

EDIT1:

```
class MyGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)
        self.geometry("400x300")

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

    def quit_app(self):
        self._frame.destroy()
        self.destroy()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        global install_svc

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    def entry_check(self,parent):
        global install_svc
```

Comment: Where exactly is the `global` statement and when/where does this error occur?

Comment: @martineau `class StartPage(tk.Frame):  def __init__(self, parent)  global install_svc` and in `PageOne` method  after some routine `def entry_check(self,parent):global install_svc`. As I thought with 3rd I can achieve what I want.

Comment: Please refer to changes in terms of changes since you haven't posted any code of your own. To help you we need to be able to reproduce the problem. You also need to show the entire error message include traceback indicating where it occurs. Just sticking in some `global` statement couldn't cause the `NameError` by itself.

Comment: I don't get any errors running the code you have added to your question.

Comment: @martineau the OP is not using `install_svc` anywhere, just doing `global install_svc` and that, alone, wont throw any error. He needs to post the error and a more complete and verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare and initialize `install_svc` at the root level (global scope). The statement `global install_svc` wont auto-magically create, by itself, the variable in the global scope: it will just do a lookup for a global variable with such name but, if you try to use that variable without first assigning something to it, a `NameError` will be thrown.

## Code

```
install_svc = None # Or some other initial value

class MyGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)
        self.geometry("400x300")

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

    def quit_app(self):
        self._frame.destroy()
        self.destroy()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        global install_svc

        # You can use install_svc safely
        print(install_svc)

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    def entry_check(self,parent):
        global install_svc

        # You can use install_svc safely
        print(install_svc)
```

You could also check if the variable exists, doing a `try..except`, but that will be **really ugly** (at least for me) and you will need to do such check everywhere:

```
class MyGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)
        self.geometry("400x300")

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

    def quit_app(self):
        self._frame.destroy()
        self.destroy()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        global install_svc

        try:
            install_svc
        except NameError:
            install_svc = None # Or some initial value

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    def entry_check(self,parent):
        global install_svc

        try:
            install_svc
        except NameError:
            install_svc = None # Or some initial value
```

Comment: I think my problem, is that I call variable from `PageOne` method . In `PageOne` I check connection to SQL DB and if everything satisifes conditions then button at `StartPage` is active

Comment: @RostislavAleev did my answer work for you? If so, please, mark it as **accepted** (green checkmark), otherwise, let me know what went wrong. Thnx in advance!

Comment: It works. But I don't think outer global variable is a good idea. I prefered 3rd frame (class). Accepted. Sorry, forgot to answer.